# "insert data" query in jena

Tags: sparql, jena, ontology

I'm using Jena API for my sparql queries. this is one of my "select" queries:

```
package mypackage;

import org.apache.jena.query.Query;
import org.apache.jena.query.QueryExecution;
import org.apache.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory;
import org.apache.jena.query.QueryFactory;
import org.apache.jena.query.QuerySolution;
import org.apache.jena.query.ResultSet;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.InfModel;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import org.apache.jena.reasoner.Reasoner;
import org.apache.jena.reasoner.ReasonerRegistry;
import org.apache.jena.util.FileManager;

public class myclass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Model schema = FileManager.get().loadModel("G:/myproj.owl");
        Reasoner reasoner = ReasonerRegistry.getOWLReasoner();
        reasoner = reasoner.bindSchema(schema);
        InfModel infmodel = ModelFactory.createInfModel(reasoner,schema);
        
        String querystring = 
                  "        PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>\r\n"
                + "        PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>\r\n"
                + "        PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>\r\n"
                + "        PREFIX myonto: <http://www.example.com/myproj#>\r\n"
                + "SELECT ?x WHERE {?x myonto:HasParent ?z}";
        
        Query query = QueryFactory.create(querystring);
        QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query,infmodel);
        try {
                ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect();
                for ( ; results.hasNext(); ) {
                    QuerySolution soln = results.nextSolution();
                    System.out.println(soln);
                }
            
        } finally { qexec.close(); }
        
    }

}
```

I want to write "insert data" query to add some individuals of relations to my ontology. I couldn't find any documentation for this. finally I write this query:

```
package mypackage;

import org.apache.jena.query.Query;
import org.apache.jena.query.QueryExecution;
import org.apache.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory;
import org.apache.jena.query.QueryFactory;
import org.apache.jena.query.QuerySolution;
import org.apache.jena.query.ResultSet;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.InfModel;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import org.apache.jena.reasoner.Reasoner;
import org.apache.jena.reasoner.ReasonerRegistry;
import org.apache.jena.update.UpdateAction;
import org.apache.jena.update.UpdateFactory;
import org.apache.jena.update.UpdateRequest;
import org.apache.jena.util.FileManager;

public class myclass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Model schema = FileManager.get().loadModel("G:/myproj.owl");
        Reasoner reasoner = ReasonerRegistry.getOWLReasoner();
        reasoner = reasoner.bindSchema(schema);
        InfModel infmodel = ModelFactory.createInfModel(reasoner,schema);
        
        String insertDataQueryString = 
                  "        PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>\r\n"
                + "        PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>\r\n"
                + "        PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>\r\n"
                + "        PREFIX onto: <http://www.example.com/myproj#>\r\n"
                + "INSERT DATA {\n" +
                "  onto:Criss onto:HasParent onto:Anna.\n" +
                "}";
        
        // Use UpdateAction to execute the "INSERT DATA" query
        UpdateRequest updateRequest = UpdateFactory.create(insertDataQueryString);
        UpdateAction.execute(updateRequest, infmodel);
             
        infmodel.write(System.out, "TURTLE");       
    }
}
```

but it didn't work and my ontology (myproj.owl) didn't change (the triple didn't add)

Comment: cannot reproduce this, took an empty model instead of your `schema` (which doesn't matter for testing your code) and I can see a triple in the output: `<http://www.example.com/myproj#Criss>
        <http://www.example.com/myproj#HasParent>
                <http://www.example.com/myproj#Anna> .`

Comment: Note: that your ontology file on disk doesn't change should be obvious, right? I mean the model is loaded into memory, if you want to change the file then you have to write back the model to disk.

Comment: @UninformedUser yes. but how can i do this? i can't find any documentation

Comment: Can do what? I mean, the method `.write()` takes an `OutputStream` as first argument. So why not using that and just write to the same file?

Comment: @UninformedUser I'm very new to jena and java. I can't find out what should I pass to the first and second argument of .write()

Comment: the same as you already did, the first argument is any Java `OutputStream`, in your case then use a `FileOutputStream` where you use your filename in the constructor. The second argument is as is, it's the serialization format of RDF data, i.e. `"Turtle"`

Comment: @UninformedUser thanks so much. if I want to save it as owl data (the format is owl) what is the second parameter?

Comment: @UninformedUser thanks for your help. please post it as answer and I will give you  rate

Comment: I guess it's better if you post it as an answer. You have the working code. Feel free to answer and also accept your own answer. That's totally valid